# Trying to map System.Collections.Generic.List 1 Exception is thrown

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map RecordDTO and Record. But when I run the application, an exception is thrown.

```
RecordBL recordBL = new RecordBL();                
List<Record> record = recordBL.GetAllRecords();
Mapper.CreateMap<RecordDTO, Record>();
List<RecordDTO> recordDTO = Mapper.Map<List<Record>,List<RecordDTO>>ecgrecord);
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
return recordDTO;
```

The exception is something like this:

> Trying to map
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1[[Server.BusinessEntities.Record, 
>   Server.BusinessEntities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List1[[DTOs.RecordDTO,Server.DTOs,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].

Could some one help me out with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to map *from* Record *to* RecordDTO, so you need:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Record, RecordDTO>();
```

Comment: I have been trying it for so long, but its just a small mistake. Thank you!